# Redirects to path with "/" at the end

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got redirects from /something to /something/ with that setting at my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I want to add the same thing for pages which ends on 123.html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [0-9]+\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[0-9]+\.html[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

It does't work... BUT!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [0-9]+\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[0-9]+\.htm.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

That variant works perfect! Why apache does't like "l"? Who knows?

Apache version: 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted not working rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[0-9]+\.html[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Which doesn't work because your regex is incorrect as your Request URI is ending with `.html` and there is nothing after `.html`. Hence `\.html[^/]` doesn't match the URI but `\.htm.*[^/]` does match as last `[^/]` matches letter `l`.

**Correct rule** would be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[0-9]+\.html)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

**PS:** You also don't need to use `RewriteCond`